# Always displays the same

Tags: javascript, html

The code is always displaying the Day image...

```
var dayOrNight = window.prompt ('Day or Night?');
if (dayOrNight = 'Day') {
    document.write ( '<img src = \"https://c.tadst.com/gfx/sunrise.png\" width ="1350" height = "630">' );
} else if (dayOrNight = 'Night') {
    document.write ( '<img src = \"http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-night-sky-night-sky-by-gallifreyanoceansoul-640.png\" width = "100" height = "100">' );
}
```

Debugging does not give me errors, but there's a bug I can't solve.

Comment: The problem is inside if condition, use == instead of a single =, single = is assignment operator, you need comparison operator == here.

Answer (score 1):

### Why doesn't this work?

The basic assumption that the `=` operator tests `equality` is wrong here. Instead of checking for equality using `=`, you should be using `===`.

### Types of operators:

`=` : assignment operator

`==` : casting equality operator (generally should avoid!)

`===` : type-equality operator (use this most of the time!)

```
var dayOrNight = window.prompt ('Day or Night?');
if (dayOrNight === 'Day') {
    document.write ( '<img src = \"https://c.tadst.com/gfx/sunrise.png\" width ="1350" height = "630">' );
} else if (dayOrNight === 'Night') {
    document.write ( '<img src = \"http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-night-sky-night-sky-by-gallifreyanoceansoul-640.png\" width = "100" height = "100">' );
}
```

is the correct code.

Comment: Thanks!! I already know that, but using === the code only works is the Mayus and LowerCases are just exactly as I said in the IF Statement... So, how con I get the same by using either 'Day' or 'day'? Thanks again!!

Comment: in this case, you would have to change the string to uppercase, then compare, like: `dayOrNight.toUpperCase() === "DAY"`

Comment: Thanks bro!! This was really helpful!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help